# PHP / Sessions Shopping Cart - Quantity in cart only updates for first item

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

Been revising my code for my **add to cart function** and I am having some difficulties with it not updating the quantity if the product is already present in the cart.  **It only updates it correctly for the first product added to cart.**

[image: Example of add to cart not updating quantity]

My **UPDATED** add to cart code is:

```
// -------------------------    
// Adding item
// -------------------------    
case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
        $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . $_GET["product_id"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["product_id"]=>array('product_name'=>$productByCode[0]["product_name"], 'product_description'=>$productByCode[0]["product_description"],
        'product_id'=>$productByCode[0]["product_id"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'product_price'=>$productByCode[0]["product_price"],'image'=>$productByCode[0]["image"]));

        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode[0]["product_id"], array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productByCode[0]["product_id"] == $k) {
                            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                            }
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                        }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
    }
break;
```

Am I missing something in the code?

Thanks.
Stan.

**Edit:
Updated code doesnt work:**

```
    // -------------------------    
// Adding item
// -------------------------    
case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
        $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . $_GET["product_id"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["product_id"]=>array('product_name'=>$productByCode[0]["product_name"], 'product_description'=>$productByCode[0]["product_description"],
        'product_id'=>$productByCode[0]["product_id"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'product_price'=>$productByCode[0]["product_price"],'image'=>$productByCode[0]["image"]));

        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode[0]["product_id"], array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productByCode[0]["product_id"] == $k) {
                            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {

                                **foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k =>&$v){

                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];   

                                }**

                            }
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                        }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: As you've now posted your live URL and information about your database structure, you'll want to take this offline *immediately*. Anybody on the net can now wipe out your database.

Comment: Linking to a demo isn't the best approach to getting help here. Please review [SO's how to create a Minimal, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include your html of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Flame suit on:

I believe when you did this

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"][$v]["quantity"] = $v++;
```

PHP actually created a copy of the array you're iterating over

Since you want to write to this array, you should explicitly iterate over by reference using `&`

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k =>&$v)...
```

Comment: My apologies, that line was changed by me to test the output. I have now updated the original post with the code that works.

Comment: The basic premise remains, once you attempt to write to the array you must do so by reference and not value

Comment: Edited main post to show code used with the above, still no luck. I dont understand why it works for the first product but then none after that.

Comment: Anyone else able to offer any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
here Im storing data in session 
$pr_id = product Id

```
adding item to cart
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart_items']))
        {
            //find index of an array if it exits then do not add else add to cart and then
            if (!array_key_exists($pr_id,$_SESSION['cart_items']))
            {
                $_SESSION['cart_items'][$pr_id]['id'] = $pr_id;
                $_SESSION['cart_items'][$pr_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart_items'][$pr_id]['id'] = $pr_id;
            $_SESSION['cart_items'][$pr_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;        
        }
        $arr = array();
        $arr['count'] = count($_SESSION['cart_items']);
        $arr['message'] = 'Item successFully added';
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

this is working code you can make update entry in db

For updating entry or quantity of product

```
if (array_key_exists($pr_id,$_SESSION['cart_items']))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart_items'][$pr_id]['quantity']=$quantity;
    }
    $arr['count'] = count($_SESSION['cart_items']);
    $arr['message'] = 'Quantity changed successfully. ';
    $arr['status']  = true;
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I dont really want to change all of the code. I must be missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I made same mistake as you did. 
This is how i resolved it:

Don't use `product_id`. `product_id` is a number. 
Use something that is combination of numbers and letters like product_name. 
It worked for me.

```php
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . $_GET["product_name"] . "'");
```